# Djangoのフォームを任意個数生成する方法

Tags: python, python3, django

Djangoでフォームを作るとき

```
from django import forms

class SampleForm(forms.Form):
     変数 = forms.CharField()
             :
```

の様に書くと思うのですが，
ユーザーの指定した個数のフォームが欲しい場合，

```
配列[key] = forms.CharField()
```

のような書き方ができないか調べています．
どなたかご存じの方はおられないでしょうか．
djangoのバージョンは2.1.2です.
よろしくお願いいたします．

Comment: FormクラスはBaseFormフォームを継承しているようですが，どうやらその際メタクラスを使ってFormクラスの変数をfieldsというOrderedDictに格納しているようです．そのため，リストや辞書型配列などは使えないというように認識しています(曖昧なので間違いがあればご指摘ください)．exec()を使えば一応は大丈夫そうだと思いますが可読性を考えるともう少しスマートな書き方が出来ないものかと考えています．

Answer (score 1):

自己解決しましたのでTipsとして残しておきます．
コメントに書いたexecをつかった方法ではうまく行きませんでした．

サンプルコード

```
#Formクラスのインポート
from django import forms

#空のクラスを用意
class EmptyClass(forms.Form):
    pass

#メインとなる関数
def create_form(myary, *arg):
    f = EmptyClass(*arg)
    for val in myary:
        f.fields[val] = forms.CharField(label=val)
    return f
```

このcreate_formにテンプレートで使いたい名前を入れた配列を投げてやれば，そのフィールドが入ったFormクラスを返してくれます．

引数の部分を辞書型配列に変えたりして使うと良さそう．

不備，不具合等あればご指摘いただけると幸いです．